# Getting back to the fragment which calls another activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, onbackpressed

I have my MainActivity which has two fragments, say fragment1 and fragment2. Now when the activity starts the default fragment is fragment1. Then I navigate to fragment2, which in turn creates another activity say CalledActivity on some event changes. What I want is to be able to navigate back to fragment2 rather than fragment1 on back press in CalledActivity. How can I accomplish that?

Looked at few SO questions, there seems to be no clear answer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

   private Toolbar toolbar;

//for display of  name and email inside the navigation drawer header
private TextView name_header;
private TextView email_header;
private String nameChar;

AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLogin();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /**
     *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
     */

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name_header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_header);
    email_header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_header);

    name_header.setText(Config.USER_FULL_NAME);
    email_header.setText(Config.USER_EMAIL);

    nameChar= Utils.parseName(Config.USER_FULL_NAME);

    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(nameChar, Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_name);
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    /**
     * Lets inflate the very first fragment
     * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
     */

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new PrimaryFragment()).commit();


    /**
     * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
     */
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_product) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new ProductsFragment()).addToBackStack( "products fragment commit" ).commit();

            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_home) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new UploadImageFragment()).addToBackStack( "home fragment commit" ).commit();
            }

            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_order) {
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).addToBackStack( "orders fragment commit" ).commit();
            }


            return true;
        }

    });


    /**
     * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
     */


    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        this.finish();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String stredittext = data.getStringExtra("edittextvalue");
            Log.d("xyz",stredittext);
        }
    }
}





}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener or this FragmentBreadCrumbs. Seems like it might help.

Comment: That depends on how you manage fragments in the first activity.
Can you post the source code?

Comment: Check if your onCreate() method is called when you navigate back to the first Activity. If so, your activity is being destroyed somehow.

Comment: if you press the hardware back button, where did you go? on the fragment1 or fragment2?

Comment: It goes back to fragment2 if hardware button is pressed.

Comment: ok..so you want to go to fragment2 with the "up" button on the actionbar...right?

Comment: yes I want to go back to fragment2 i.e. it is the fragment which creates the new activity. Fragment1 is the fragment which is rendered by default when the MainActivity is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override the `onOptionsItemSelected` method on your `CalledActivity` activity like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```